# image alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I have used different brand images in different width and height. I want to display the images in horizontally and vertically centered. Please see the following Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/FXQhv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIve `line-height` same as `height` of the DIV. Write like this:

```
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box {
    float: left;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/FXQhv/1/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to define line-height so now you just have to add line-height in your css :

```
    .ngg-gallery-thumbnail {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/FXQhv/3/

[read more about Centering (horizontally and vertically) an image in a box](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following

```
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box a { display:table-cell; width:120px; height:100px; vertical-align:middle; }
```